# How to get Angular router to ignore query string params?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-routerlink

I have an Angular 16 application with routing.  I have some links in other places that will redirect to this application with a query string appended like this: `http://my-app.com?redirect=other-app.com`

When the query string is present, it cannot properly set the `routerLinkActive` class specified.  This is due to `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"` being set, but I have to set this here on the home page or else it will be set as active for all other pages

```html
<a routerLinkActive="active"
   routerLink="/"
   [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"> Home </a>
<a routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="/about"> About </a>
```

```ts
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  ...
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      initialNavigation: 'enabledBlocking',
    }),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Is there a way to get the router to ignore query string params, or is there some other way to do this that I'm missing?

EDIT: I have since found out that it's possible to set `queryParams: 'ignored'` like this:

```
<a routerLinkActive="active"
   routerLink="/"
   [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true, queryParams: 'ignored' }"> Home </a>
```

which seems like it should work, but it has no effect.

Comment: not sure if angular provide it natively but we can manage it in the component ts by checking manually.

Comment: Do you mean that I should manually check for query strings on load and then remove them and redirect to a URL without them?

Comment: you can check with location.pathname and it will return "/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a better way to do this, but here's what I ended up doing

```ts
public isHomePage = false;

constructor(private router: Router) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
    if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      this.isHomePage = event.url === '/' || event.url.startsWith('/?');
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<a routerLink="/" [class.active]="isHomePage ">Home</a>
```

now the following URLs will highlight this route as expected:

- `/`
- `/?`
- `/?foo=bar`

But any other route will not highlight this route.